# substitute key name for subset of ruby sliced elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the following ruby slice command runs as expected

```
@points.map{ |a| a.slice('point', 'point_name') }
```

returning and array of keys and values.

However, before dumping the array of hashes off to json, the goal is to transform the key 'point_name' to 'title'.  Attempting a rails helper, as such

```
@points.map{ |a| a.slice('point', 'point_name' as: 'title') }
```

fails.  What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such syntax in ruby. Key rename can be achieved like this:

```
@points.map do |a| 
  a['title'] = a.delete('point_name')
  a.slice('point', 'title')
end
```

You may need json serializer (as you mentioned Rails), consider using [FastJsonApi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi).